# Login issue with mySQL no database selected

Tags: php, mysql

I'm a beginner of PHP coding which I face this problem and I tried to fix it.
I have search through stackoverflow for answers but it stills no good.

This is my Login form.php file

```
<form name = 'LoginForm' method = 'POST' action = 'verifyUser.php'>
<br />
E-MAIL: <input type = "Textbox" Name = "App_Email"><br><br>
PASSWORD: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type = "password" Name = "App_Password"><br><br>

<input type = 'Submit' name = 'Login' value = 'Log in'><br><br>
</form>
```

This form will goes to verifyUser.php and these are codes

```
include ('DBconnect.php'); 
 $username = $_POST['App_Email'];
 $pass  = $_POST['App_Password'];
 if($username=='' || $pass=='') {
        header("Location:login.php?id=Some fields are empty");
    }

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM applicant_acct ");

if(!$result) {
    die("Query Failed: ". mysql_error());
} else {

    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

    if ($username==$row['App_Email']) {
        if($username==$row['App_Email'] && $pass==$row['App_Password']) {
            header("Location: index.html?id=$username");
        } else {
            header("Location:login.php?id=username or your password is incorrect. Please try again");
        }
    }
}
```

And final DBconnect.php

```
<?
$dbc = mysql_connect('localhost','root','root') OR die('Wrong Connection!!!!!!!');
mysql_select_db('onlinerecruitment') OR die ('Cannot connect to DB.');
?>
```

I really have no idea why it shows "Query Failed: No database selected"
I think the problem is in verifyUser.php but have no idea where.

And another thing, after I logged in how can I generate the text "Welcome - "Username"" and provide them the logout button?

Please help.
Thank you.

Comment: Use `mysql_connect('localhost','root','')`

Comment: It will connected without password?

Comment: No need to use password

Answer (score 0):

Generally you may want to research a graphical user interface such as XAMPP or MySQL workbench until you are more comfortable with Database systems.

Here it seems like most of the improvements can be made in you DBConnect.php file. You are beginning and I can appreciate that. Consider something along the following lines that incorporates additional the security of PDO:: static calls.

```
<?php 

public function _dbconnect($hostpath, $database, $username, $password){

try {

  $this->conn = new PDO("mysql:host = {$hostpath};
                         dbname - {$database};
                         charset = utf8", 
                         $username, 
                         $password);

} else { exit(); }
?>
```

If this particular code block doesn't help I would highly recommend that you continue by investigating PDO:: calls.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
include ('DBconnect.php'); 
if(isset($_POST['Login'])){
   $username = $_POST['App_Email'];
   $pass  = $_POST['App_Password'];
   if(empty($username) || empty($pass) || ctype_space($username) || ctype_space($pass)){
   header("Location:login.php?error=1");
} else {
   $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM applicant_acct");
   if(!$result) {
      die("Query Failed: ". mysql_error());
   } else {
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    if($username==$row['App_Email'] && $pass==$row['App_Password']) {
       header("Location: index.php?id=$username");
    } else {
       header("Location:login.php?error=0");
    }
}
?>
```

I have a lot to say about your code.

1. Use isset function . This function check if something was done.
2. Check your database details again.  Maybe you wrote something
   wrong (misclick or something)
3. Use `$_GET['error']` to get errors. I set 1 = for empty characters and 0 for 0 match between database and inputs.
4. Use sessions for after login message. You can also use Session to handle your errors.

EDIT: I recommend you to start to learn MySQLi or PDO.